# How to show that the following function is bijective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If we have the function $c : \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N} : (x,y) \rightarrow 2^x \cdot (2y+1) -1 $ how to show that this function is bijective?

So I thought the easiest way is to show that is injective and surjective, but this leads me to the next problem, how to show those sides. So how to show that every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ from the target set gets hit and every $(x,y)$ hits another $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ from the target set?

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: Note that for this to work, $\mathbb{N}$ has to be the non-negative integers. For the positive integers one needs to modify things a little.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: can we not quietly forget those dark days of yesteryear when some authors deprived $\Bbb{N}$ of one its most valuable members $\ddot{\smile}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bijectivity of this function is really a weakened form of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic: it's saying that every $n \ge 1$ can be expressed uniquely as a power of two multiplied by an odd number. The '$-1$' in your function just shifts this down by one to account for $0$ being a natural number.

So:

- To prove injectivity, fix $x,y,x',y' \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose $2^x(2y+1)-1=2^{x'}(2y'+1)-1$. Add $1$ to both sides of the equation and then use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to deduce $x=x'$, and then deduce $y=y'$.
- To prove surjectivity, fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to express $n+1$ as a power of $2$ multiplied by an odd number.

Comment: More generally, to show that a function $f$ is bijective, simply show that it is injective (i.e. - that f(x) = f(x) implies that  x = y) and that it is surjective (that the range of function is equal to the co-domain; that is, for a function $f: A \rightarrow B$, $\forall y \in B, \exists x \in A f(x) = y$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the intuition behind this bijection is this: $c(x, y) = 2^x\cdot(2y + 1) - 1= 2^{x+1}y + 2^x - 1$, so $c(x, y)$, is the number whose binary represention is the binary representation of $y$ followed by a $0$ followed by the unary representation of $x$ (i.e., by $x$ $1$s).